# spatie/crawler - How to get HTML of a javascript rendered website?

Tags: javascript, html, web-crawler

I am trying to use spatie/crawler to crawl a javascript rendered website for login.

```
$crawler = Crawler::create();
$browsershot = new Browsershot();
$browsershot->noSandbox();
$crawler->setBrowsershot($browsershot);
$crawler
->executeJavaScript()
->ignoreRobots()
->setCrawlObserver(new Observer())
->startCrawling($url);
```

After crawling, the $response->getBody()->getContents(), still return javascript.

```
<script src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/js/p2m.min.js?v=1634828250979.5806"></script>
    
    <animateTransform data-v-5ca127d8="" attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0 20 20" to=" ▶
    var p2mSubprogramCode = '';
    var programType = 'grsexternal';
    var cacheTtl = '3600';
```

How I can get the HTML? So that I can select the button for login.

```
<form id="loginform" reset="true">
...
<div class="form-group"><button id="btn-login" type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Sign In</button></div>
```